# Add to odata collection property in .NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, odata, odata-v4

Using the odata-v4 service connection in visual studio C# .NET, I get an entity of type `testDefinition`. `testDefinition` has property called `features` which is a collection of entities of type `feature`.

In the DB, `testDefinition` to `feature` is many to many with a junction table.

[image]

In my code, I add a service reference to a web service serving the EDMX of the DB.

Code gets generated correctly and I run:

```
var dsc = new Container(new Uri("http://webserver/webapi/odata/"));

var someFeature = new Feature
{
    name = $"Sample feature created with C# {DateTime.UtcNow}",
};

var someOtherFeature = new Feature
{
    name = $"Sample other feature created with C# {DateTime.UtcNow}",
};

dsc.AddToFeature(someFeature);
dsc.AddToFeature(someOtherFeature);

dsc.SaveChanges();

var someTestDefinition = new TestDefinition
{
    name = $"Sample test created with C# {DateTime.UtcNow}",
    description = $"A nice succinct description",
};    

dsc.AddToTestDefinition(someTestDefinition);
dsc.SaveChanges();

someTestDefinition.features.Add(someFeature);
someTestDefinition.features.Add(someOtherFeature);

dsc.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is the mapping from the test definition to features is not recorded in the database.

Has anyone encountered this issue, or better yet, resolved it?

For Reference:

[image]

Comment: What is the server? If you are using Microsoft’s OData WebAPI for the server, it doesn’t support odata.bind in request bodies, even though the OData client from Microsoft will generate requests with odata.bind directives (https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/158), I would recommend intercepting the request JSON body sent to the server to have a look. It is possible to implement your own support for odata.bind on the server side (I’ve done this in one of my own projects), but it is challenging.

Comment: It is MS WebApi - thank for the info. You should add it as an answer.

Comment: I will actually add my solution for implementing odata.bind as an answer, but it may take a day or two, what version of the OData WebAPI are you using (the solution makes use of some library ‘internals’ that got changed a lot in recent version)?

Comment: Not sure - There's so many references to ODATA in my project now, I'm a bit confused. I'm adding a screenshot of my odata refs to the body of the question. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the Microsoft.Data.OData reference. That's for v3 and not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say when this was implemented but it works in later versions, the earliest verison I can confirm this against is `OData.Client v 7.6.2`

If this is an issue for any new users on *current* versions of the OData *Client* and *Server* libraries it generally indicates that the schema is not correctly configured or published.

Also check that the API uses a similarly current OData runtime, the above test was performed against API with `Microsoft.AspNet.OData v7.3.0`